# Don't work spring.config.additional-location

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

maven:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
           <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <active.spring.profile>local</active.spring.profile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=@active.spring.profile@
spring.config.additional-location=classpath:/profile/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties
```

and after this I can't get value from src/main/resources/application-local.properties which contains `test.prop=123`

```
@Service
public class TestProps {

    @Value("${test.prop}")
    String testProp;

    @PostConstruct
    void run() {
        System.out.println(testProp);
    }
}
```

Where is the mistake? or it's a bug?

Comment: (1) your link is broken, (2) precisely to avoid such risks in the future we require from questions to have minimal, but complete code example which will let us reproduce the problem in the question itself instead of a link. Please see [mcve].

Comment: the url is fixed

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The property: `spring.config.additional-location` has to be provided as argument for JVM like this: `java -Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:/profile/application-local.properties -jar whatever.jar`.

Doesn't make sense to have it in `application.properties`. From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> Alternatively, when custom config locations are configured by using
> spring.config.additional-location, they are used in addition to the
> default locations. **Additional locations are searched before the
> default locations**.

Because the additional locations are searched **before** the default locations, they have to be provided earlier, so you can't have them in `application.properties`

Comment: THANKS. I was passing it using -Dspring.config.additional-location which does not work at all. (but works through VM options in IntelliJ's run configuration)

Comment: @petronius most rpobably you were passing that IN WORNG place - it must be BEFORE `-jar` switch otherwise it will end up as arg to `main` method instead of env variable.

Comment: OMG this worked. I did exactly the same mistake although I read the documentation -.-

Answer (score 4):

additional-location really does not belong to application.properties, because Spring will not interpret it from there. It needs to load the additional config files before the default ones.
On the other hand, it is handy to set the default additional location in maven spring boot plugin. This way one would be able to set security-sensitive information outside of the project sources and it will not appear in the source repository. For example, the client security config could read:

```
app:
  client:
    ssl: 
      keystore: path/to/keystore
      keystore-password: the-keystore-password
      key-password: the-key-password
```

Default application.yml in src/main/resources can be skipped, while the additional config could provide the values per active profile and keep them safe on the local machine.