# Tomcat set external properties file for db

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am running spring boot 2.1.0

I want to place my db-properties.yml file external to my webapp directory.

I have created a new **setenv.sh** in my tomcat bin folder to this:

```
export spring_config_additional-location=/path/to/file/db-properties.yml
```

and I have place the file, db-properties.yml in that path.

```
spring:
  datasource:
     username: username
     url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.122.2:1521:xe
     password: password
```

But I am getting this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You above display not `.properties` it is `.yml` file

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have changed to .yml and restarted Tomcat but the error message is still the same. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You should export `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONALLOCATION` and is it the path or the full path to the file? If it is just the path without the filename it will not load anything unless you instruct Spring Boot to load files named` db-properties` as well as `application`.

Comment: I have tried putting in the filename too but the error message is still the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't work spring.config.additional-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729748/dont-work-spring-config-additional-location)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem by overriding the below method in the main class of spring boot.

````
        /**
         * For External Properties
         */
        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder) {
            logger.info("\nLoading properties as configured...\n");
            return springApplicationBuilder.sources(MainApplication.class).properties(getProperties());
        }

        static Properties getProperties() {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(YourConstantsFile.SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION,
                    "file:///xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx.yml");
            return props;
        }

    This will serve the purpose when you deploy the application as a war as well.

    Along with this, for locally running I included the below snippet too.

    @PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file://${your.custom.file}", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
    })
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{}


    Application.properties.


    server-home=${catalina.home}/anyfolder/
    your.custom.file=${server-home}/xxx.yml

```
````